# How to automatically start 2 Java jars on AWS EC2?

Tags: java, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jar

I'm learning to deploy Spring Boot apps on AWS EC2. And I know how to automate app launch, when I start the EC2 instance, I don't need to manually use the command java -jar java-service.jar, I just add this command in the /etc/rc.local file and that is all. But I have 2 microservice, and I want to start both of them automatically, but if I try to add both commands in the /etc/rc.local it's not working, only the first service will start, the second service will not start.
So I have the commands added like this:

[image]

And after I start the EC2 instance only the first service is started:

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not a unix expert, but I see the only issue in running 2 java commands from terminal is that unless the first command returns, the next command is not executed. So, I think the solution would be run the 1st command in some interactive mode so that the other commands can be executed simultaneously.

There are ways in unix shell to run a command in background. I found this useful link - https://www.maketecheasier.com/run-bash-commands-background-linux/

In bash terminal, a command can be made to run in background by appending it with `&`. So, I think you should be able to start both jars if you do something like -

```
java -jar /home/ec2-user/first.jar &
java -jar /home/ec2-user/second.jar
```

Answer (score 3):

I recommend to use Systemd.
Create a Systemd unit file for every microservice, save it in `/etc/systemd/system/my-app.service`. Something like that:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Java app
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/my-app-env
WorkingDirectory=/my/app/home
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java $JAVA_OPTS -jar my-app.jar
KillMode=process
User=my-app-user
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then, run:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable --now my-app
```

After that, you can use:

```
systemctl status my-app
systemctl stop my-app
systemctl start my-app
```

Comment: Great solution @MarcoCaberletti.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to bundle your jars into Docker images. This of course requires Docker runtime and adds an overhead, but it also has some benefits:

- Complete separation of jar files. Easily use different java versions.
- No need to worry about differences of local and ec2 environment.
- Easily scale to 3 or more jars.
- Use Docker Cli to build and start containers. Works great in a Devops Pipeline.

You can read [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/) to learn how to create Spring Boot Docker images. After you build an image. You start it like this.:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 springio/gs-spring-boot-docker
```

You can run as many docker run commands you need, one after another.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which system you are using in starting application:
For linux base system, you can use crontab to schedule the task when the server reboot.
Follow this steps:

1. Download crontab

   #apt-get install cron
2. Edit the file file to enable the task

   crontab -e

   (Choose Vim or nano to edit the task)
3. Add this code to your server

   @reboot /usr/bin/java -jar XXXXX.jar
4. Save your file
5. Check the result

   crontab -l
   #systemctl status cron

This method works in my Debian system. For more details, you can refer to
[How to automatically run program on Linux startup](https://www.simplified.guide/linux/automatically-run-program-on-startup)

Answer (score 0):

If you are running from bash, then join two jar commands with "&" like below.

```
java -jar /home/ec2-user/first.jar&java -jar /home/ec2-user/second.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

**coupon service**

1. Run the command 'java -jar /home/ec2-user/coupon-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.JAR'
2. Press CTRL+Z, type bg, press Enter, type disown, press Enter.

**product service**

1. Run the command 'java -jar /home/ec2-user/product-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.JAR'
2. Press CTRL+Z, type bg, press Enter, type disown, press Enter.

**NOTE**: Both services should have different ports.